# My brother and I have different pings

Tags: networking

My brother and I use the same router, comcast internet, and are both using ethernet.

However, our pings are different:

[image]

My ping is 15, however my brother's is 8.

Comment: Clearly it **can** be calculated.  (-:  "[affect](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/315/)" by the way.

Comment: @JdeBP - Please be post productive comment towards me. You only correcting my grammar is not appreciated at least in the case where you ignore the user's question.  I still maintain you would not notice a performance difference between  8ms vs 15ms ping times.  Furthermore one was a spectator which could have had an affect on the pings itself.

Comment: I didn't use the word affect *or* effect in my post. Also, I know the difference between the two and use them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that these are "real" pings - what you are most likely seeing is an in-game ping, which - for many games - takes into account the speed of the computer being used.

There are also other possibilities - like you are connecting to different servers (using round-robin DNS or similar).

You might want to do some proper "Windows" pings to various IP addresses to see if it is a network problem (unlikely) or something else.  If you suspect you might be going to different IP's, you would probably need a packet sniffer to ascertain where the packets are going.

Comment: My computer is *much* faster than his. His is a budget laptop and mine is a $3000 gaming computer. I tried speedtest.net on both of them and his ping is better than mine, using the same server.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like a network problem then.  I would compare pings to the switch, then try different cables, switch ports etc.  If the pings are similar to the switch it might be a QoS thing on the router (but thats not that likely).  Also try running WinMTR and see if you are getting packet loss, and where its coming in [ also where the latency changes become apparent ]

Comment: Different OS perhaps?

Comment: Both running windows 8. I tried switching the ethernet cables, nothing happened.